# Unit testing an executor callable

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a controller class like this that passes some executor into an instance of runnable.
This isn't how it works but just for simplicity I did it like this.

```
package com.test.executor;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Controller {
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public Controller() {
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    public void doRun() {
        MyRunner runner = new MyRunner(executor);
        Thread myRunner = new Thread(runner);
        myRunner.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Controller().doRun();
    }
}
```

The runner receives the instance of the executor and then passes certain callables.
Now, the callables are a bit diverse as some callables access the database/call some web service/file system

I am having some issues on how to write a proper JUnit for this case.
I wanted to have as much code coverage as possible.

```
package com.test.executor;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class MyRunner implements Runnable {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public MyRunner(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Future<Boolean> ret1 = executor.submit(new SampleCall1());

        try {
            ret1.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Do other things

        Future<List<String>> ret2 = executor.submit(new SampleCall2());

        try {
            ret2.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Do other things

        Future<Long> ret3 = executor.submit(new SampleCall3());

        try {
            ret3.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class SampleCall1 implements Callable<Boolean> {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will call JSON web service
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleCall2 implements Callable<List<String>> {

        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will call Database
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleCall3 implements Callable<Long> {

        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will access some file system
            return 1L;
        }

    }

}
```

My question is what is the proper way to write a unit test for this.  I am gathering some advice on how I can unit test this class?
I am not sure what to mock in my junit/mockito instance.
Should I mock each callable? And then create a test case for MyRunner.

I worry about the dependency..as I am connecting into a database/a web service/and file system so I would like to ask for some advice.

**UPDATE 2**

```
package com.test.executor;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class MyRunner implements Runnable {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public MyRunner(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        executeTasks1();
        // Do other things

        executeTasks2();
        // Do other things


        executeTasks3();

    }

    public boolean executeTasks1(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Future<Boolean> ret1 = executor.submit(new SampleCall1());

        try {
            return ret1.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<String> executeTasks2(){
        Future<List<String>> ret2 = executor.submit(new SampleCall2());

        try {
            return ret2.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Long executeTasks3(){
        Future<Long> ret3 = executor.submit(new SampleCall3());

        try {
            return ret3.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class SampleCall1 implements Callable<Boolean> {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will call JSON web service
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleCall2 implements Callable<List<String>> {

        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will call Database
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleCall3 implements Callable<Long> {

        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            // Sample Return Only
            // This will access some file system
            return 1L;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just unit test the Callables separately and mock the executor with appropriate “answers” to test the logic of “MyRunner”.

Comment: I don't understand your issue : the entire concept of callable & executor is to separate the intelligence of the callable from the execution scheduling logic. Now, when **unit** testing, you just need to test what you're expecting of your interfaces. TL;DR unit test the callable independently, UT your controller, don't UT the executor, because that's Spring code and don't write a test mixing everything, that's just not unitary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't spend too much time on code coverage. Be pragmatic in some way. Test what is worth testing. Increase your test quality, not quantity. Some side-note regarding metrics: 100% line coverage does not count as much as a high branch coverage and getting a high branch coverage may cost you a lot of time and even then: you may not need to take every possible route. [PIT (mutation testing)](http://pitest.org/) is a helpful "tool" which checks how good your tests actually are by changing the code under test. But use that information as a guide, not as a measure to implement even more tests. Don't exaggerate! (maybe if you are developing a library, that you don't want to change that often anymore or which you want to make rock-solid (and you have the spare-time), you can, but otherwise I wouldn't)

There was a time where I tested everything very accurately. The problem: as soon as changes kick in (like: today we require X, tomorrow it's Y) many of your tests then fail. A lot of rework is required then. If you test the most appropriate, as soon as the requirements change dramatically, you can focus on the important, which should take much less time.

Looking at the code you presented I would probably write a test (class) for each `Callable`-implementation, just so that it is ensured that they do what I want (this may lead to extraction of the `Callable`-classes as a side-effect). For the controller and the runner I am not so sure yet... The `MyRunner` seems already obsolete to me... but maybe it's not. So probably I would only test the controller...

Regarding mocking: I started omitting mocks whenever possible. Most of the times I also add integration tests and I like to know how the system acts as a whole and whether it works as expected. I have seen a lot of tests where there were so many mocks in place, that by changing any code, no unit tests have failed, even though some should have in my opinion. I've also seen lots of unit tests were the unit tests in fact looked like integration tests, but there were just mocks everywhere. What does the mock then help in the first place? Setting up the mock alone probably took way too much time. But that is again my opinion. So even though many people like the test pyramid to have a broad unit test bottom, I see it more pragmatic and move some of the tests to the integration test "layer" instead of using tons of mocks. In the end it's also a question of availability and speed. You want your tests to give fast results, still you want the results to be of most value (which mocks only give partially).

Comment: The issue that I had with code coverage is that we are required to have as much as 80% code coverage in our test.  So if I test the callable one by one then do lots of mocking..my code coverage goes really down.  Is there a simplified pattern that I could do to make my code more testable?

Comment: who wants the "80% code coverage"? What does that even mean? line coverage? branch coverage?

Comment: @MarkEstrada your coverage figure shouldn't go down, you just have more smaller test classes. Whatever gets mocked should be tested in a separate test.

Comment: I was in some projects where they forced 80% code coverage... however, the tests reaching those did not have a high quality, leading in passing tests, where there were obvious bugs... don't run for numbers... run for quality, but also: be pragmatic ;-)

Comment: Just a requirements on unit tests by the architects..when unit testing sut class.

Comment: But is it line coverage >=80%? Or branch coverage?

Comment: It is code line coverage so in MyRunnerTest class, I have to cover all of the callable call.

Comment: ok... if it's so, then there are so many sources telling that line coverage alone is not a good software metric. Just search for "line coverage bad" (or "good" if you want) and it already lists lot of things against it.

Comment: Try to convince the architects or your team, why it's a bad idea to just follow the line coverage metric.

Comment: So what if I do my Update 2?  Will these improve my test efficiency?  I will just mock all calls to executeN and create a separate test for each callable

Comment: hmmm... I would rather start going the opposite direction... I assume you know what the piece of code should do. So why don't you start with the tests first... (and try some test driven development by the way ;-)) you may come up with a better class / class hierarchy that way...

Comment: I actually have not tried TDD..but just by looking at MyRunner class.  Is there some abstraction that I could do to make it better in terms of class hierarchy.  Lets say I remove my controller class and I just have MyRunner with an executor service that calls certain callables along the way.

Comment: we are leaving the field of test and test coverage. You should really try TDD. It must not be 100% TDD at the beginning (you already have some code)... but try to set up the tests now... try to articulate them.. maybe you already realise that you rather want the setup to be completely different then your current implementation. Try to just test any of the callables now. What do you require to do that now? How is your test class then named? May it make sense to name the implementation the same? to extract it? to have it in MyRunnerTest? I think you will realise... but maybe I am wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a huge `MyRunnableTest` test classes is as much of a code smell as writing a huge `MyRunnable` production class. Since each of your `Callable`s is diverse and accesses different I/O resource you want to test each of them separately. The actual approach e.g. unit test for file system operations or integration test with embedded H2 database should be select on case by case basis.

Extracting `Callable`s should leave you with a smaller `MyRunnable` class. You can now split `run()` into smaller methods or classes and test them separately. At this point you can mock `ExecutorService`.

You should test the `ExecutorService` object in the test for `Controller` class where you have the actual object created.

Coverage is just a tool that helps you measures the quality of your tests. High coverage is not a goal in itself. If you take it to the extreme you can easily have 100% code coverage and not a single assertion in your tests.

You can apply other techniques like [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and tools like [PIT mutation testing](http://pitest.org/) to improve your tests. However you should start by making your production code easy to test.

Comment: Looking at my MyRunner  class..do you think that it is doing a lot of things?  I cannot think of a way to have it more testable because the logic is something like that.  I used callables to separate each tasks.

Comment: I am too slow... but I find it good that some parts of my answer also match yours ;-)

Comment: I even asked myself, why you require the `MyRunner`. A consequence of having a test for each callable is also that you may start to extract those if they increase in size.

Comment: @Roland @MarkEstrada I'd probably convert these callables into a regular DAO. The `ExecutorService` should be injected into the DAO, not into the Controller. This would simplify the `MyRunnable` as it won't have to deal with async semantics which will be hidden by DAO (ideally some kind of `AbstractAsyncDao` that is extended).

Comment: DAO? What does it mean?

Comment: I got an idea with your suggestion.. can you check my Update 2?  What if I extract all of my callables into separate methods..and then just mock out everything when calls to execute1,execute2 and execute 3 when I test MyRunner.  Then I will just create a separate test for each callable.  Will this increase my test efficiency?